# How to use javascript variable inside JRoute()?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

```
function getProduct(category)
{
    document.galaxy.action = '<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id='+ category) ?>';
    document.getElementById('galaxy').submit();
}
```

How can i use JavaScript variable " (category) " inside JRoute.

Help Me.

Comment: You can't Javascript is executed in the browser, PHP is executed on the server....

Answer (score 0):

```
function getProduct(category)
{
    document.galaxy.action = '<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id="'+ category+') ?>';
    document.getElementById('galaxy').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating at the end of `php` and mind the quotes `"`:

```
function getProduct(category){
    document.galaxy.action = "<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=
        com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id='"+category+"') ?>";
    document.getElementById('galaxy').submit();
}
```

Comment: does not work
syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteItem() {
    var item_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-item-id');
    if (confirm("<?php echo JText::_('COM_CN_REPORTS_DELETE_MESSAGE'); ?>")) {
        window.location.href = '<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_cn_reports&task=commoverrideform.remove&id='%2Bitem_id%2B'", false, 2); ?>';
    }
}
```

Formats in the browser as

```
function deleteItem() {
    var item_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-item-id');
    if (confirm("Are you sure that you want delete this item?")) {
        window.location.href = 'http://cnbeta2.me/index.php?option=com_cn_reports&task=commoverrideform.remove&id='+item_id+'&Itemid=262';
    }
}
```